# Can someone please show how to use getAmountOut/getAmountIn functions of UniswapV2 Router2 smart contract using ethersjs?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, ethers.js

I tried:

- getting pair of DAI-MKR pair from factory contract (using address, ABI, Infura RPC provider)
- Used this pair contract to get reserves. converted these reserves from hex to decimal using `parseInt(reserve0, 16))` and `parseInt(reserve1, 16))`
- used these in the router contract:

  const uniswapV2Router2 = (uniswapV2Router2_add, uniswapV2Router2_ABI, provider)
  const maxAmount = await uniswapV2Router2.getAmountIn(1, reserve0, reserve1)

But I got following error:

```
const maxAmount = await uniswapV2Router2.getAmountIn(1, reserve0, reserve1); // amount of MKR for 1 DAI
                                             ^

TypeError: uniswapV2Router2.getAmountIn is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

This error I guess is caused by your router abi or router address error because I do not have information on the previous code so I can only speculate it

But there are several obvious errors in your code

You should chang this

`const maxAmount = await uniswapV2Router2.getAmountIn(1, reserve0, reserve1); // amount of MKR for 1 DAI`

to

`const maxAmount = await uniswapV2Router2.getAmountIn(1, [reserve0, reserve1]); // amount of MKR for 1 DAI`.

Because [reserve0, reserve1] is an array :)